# Table per hierarchy not default behavior of EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

I'm trying to map these three classes to one EF table. In this scenario, my base class actually has a base Entity class, is this causing my issue? I'm not finding any examples that cover a scenario where the default behavior isn't handled properly.

**Base Class**:

```
public abstract class Connection : Entity
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public ContactEnums.ConnectionType Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Child Classes:**

```
public class BusinessConnection : Connection
{
    [ForeignKey("Business")]
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
    public Business Business { get; set; }
}


public class ContactConnection : Connection
{
    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity Base class:**

```
public abstract class Entity : EqualityAndHashCodeProvider<Entity, int>
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Resulting Table Structure]

Comment: For which classes do you have DbSets?

Comment: Hey there, I added one to the base Connection class and it seems to have worked. Will self-answer ASAP